# Strange "Allow" header in OPTIONS request to CORS-enabled spring boot endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot

To test this, one can use the sample code from https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ with no changes.

Here's the output from an OPTIONS request without any CORS headers:

```sh
$ curl -X OPTIONS -i http://localhost:8080/greeting                                                                                                              HTTP/1.1 200 
Allow: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 16:45:25 GMT
```

As expected, the `Allow` header is correct, as the method is annotated with `@GetMapping`.

But now let's simulate a CORS preflight OPTIONS request (which is not really necessary for a GET, but that's not the point), adding `Origin` and `Access-Control-Request-Method`:

```sh
$ curl -X OPTIONS -H'Origin: http://localhost:9000' -H'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -i http://localhost:8080/greeting
HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 16:48:36 GMT
```

The CORS headers have been correctly included, but note that `Allow` now lists more methods than actually allowed (and which are indeed not allowed, with or without CORS; a 405 "Method not allowed" error is returned if one tries to POST to that URL).

Even more strange, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` correctly lists only `GET`.

Am I misunderstanding some detail about how CORS should work, or is this a bug in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

[Allow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Allow)

> The Allow header lists the set of methods support by a resource.

[Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods)

> The Access-Control-Allow-Methods response header specifies the method or methods allowed when accessing the resource in response to a preflight request.

**Allow** just states what methods that are in general supported by the spring boot application. While **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** tells you what methods that you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

As @Thomas stated allow is a Resource response header
So if you look closely at the `@RequestMapping` properties you will see `method : RequestMethod[]` https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--

If you go to RequestMethod docs you will find the following :

> Java 5 enumeration of HTTP request methods. Intended for use with the
>   RequestMapping.method() attribute of the RequestMapping annotation.
>   Note that, by default, DispatcherServlet supports GET, HEAD, POST,
>   PUT, PATCH and DELETE only. DispatcherServlet will process TRACE and
>   OPTIONS with the default HttpServlet behavior unless explicitly told
>   to dispatch those request types as well: Check out the
>   "dispatchOptionsRequest" and "dispatchTraceRequest" properties,
>   switching them to "true" if necessary.

So by default `@RequestMapping` will allow [GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH , DELETE]
If you want to restrict some resource or method for specific methods you can use

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
```

Comment: The code is using `@GetMapping`, which is equivalent to `@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET})`. When there are not CORS headers in the request, the reply is correct, but when the CORS headers are included, the reply suddenly lists methods that are not allowed.